# Unable to connect the Weblogic server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am trying to connect the WebLogic server in the eclipse, but it pop out error,
**The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated. Required classpath for credential detection is missing. Detection is disabled.** I tried with jdk8,11,17,18 the same error is pops out. What goes wrong unable to find.

[image]

Comment: Do you have another weblogic domain on your machine using the same port that is already running?

Comment: no I have only one domain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279875/the-server-is-invalid-error-occurred-reading-server-credential-if-the-domain-w)